# Qgis2threejs plugin results images with bleeding edges and wider background canvas

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, 3d, qgis2threejs

I have started using 3D Qgis2threejs plugin in an attempt to make some beautiful 3D images of LiDAR analysis I am currently working.

I have two questions regarding that:

1. I am getting that bleeding edge (see it on screenshot) - why and what I can do to remove it?
2. Why do I get a bigger background white surface than the DEM? Is there a way to fix it?

Screenshot:
 https://mega.nz/#!AJ8DEJ7J!1iCbR4MHYkI1-R3bYpx0Rb1aLATB-4Ee9KJVU-g2veQ

Settings:
https://mega.nz/#!cQNnjQwA!zVD0j1ZW-nM9h81kjLQqQAkVwXlXZpkZ1QN7o6_vWWA

Comment: I'd suggest you if possible, to include the screenshots directly in the post, rather than providing the links. Links can break with time, and it would be easier (and faster) to understand the question by reading its content in just one place.

Comment: Please upload the images directly to Stack Exchange so they stay available forever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, well more a bypass. First step is that i draw a polygon just little smaller than map canvas. Then in QGIS2threejs plugin i select clip DEM with polygon layer. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the extent of the output model is same as that of map canvas. No-data area on the map canvas will be white and elevation zero plain of the output model and may cause the appearance of the cliff and bleeding you showed in the screenshot.

To remove the bleeding, zoom in (and rotate the map canvas) so that the map canvas is filled with the area where data exist, and then do export.